# Gravitational lensing

Tags: gravitational-lensing

I was reading about gravitational lensing. I was just curious to know if there are any formulae or methods to find the angle at which the light deflects due to **strong** gravitational lensing?

And how far should that massive object be present so that we can observe multiple images of the observing object?

Comment: Hi Ishan, it's a great question, but on this site you're expected to have done a little research yourself before asking, i.e. at least read the [wiki](https://tinyurl.com/yye89tv9), have a look at related SE questions (e.g. [here](https://tinyurl.com/y6tdzv3y), [here](https://tinyurl.com/y2feh8ev), and [here](https://tinyurl.com/y5ajzboe)), and maybe have a look at the first few Google hits, like [this](https://tinyurl.com/yxgp34rq) and [this](https://tinyurl.com/yxqoxe32). I suggest you take a look at those links and come back with more specific questions to things you don't understand :)

Comment: @Pela (and upvoters) None of those links provide anything like a quantitative answer to this question.

Comment: @RobJeffries Yeah, you're right. The question was a bit different when I wrote this comment, and seemed to me like the OP simply wanted more general knowledge on strong lensing.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely:
$$\theta = \frac{4GM}{c^2b},$$
where $\theta$ is the angle of bending, $G$ is the gravitational constant, $M$ is the mass of the star/blackhole/whatever, $c$ is the speed of light, and $b$ is the "impact parameter", the distance from the light ray to the center of the mass on its closest approach if it was NOT deflected (i.e., $b=0$ for an impact).

Comment: This is the weak field approximation. The question was asking about strong lensing.

Comment: This is a weak lensing formula that doesn't address the question asked.

Comment: I do not recall the bold term being there when I answered it!

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz that's right, I put it in boldface because apparently you didn't see it.